# How to solve the delay in executing the script developed in Selenium webdriver for the JAVA application developed using Vaadin framework?

Tags: java, vaadin

```
Thread.sleep(25000);
cmdriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div")).click();
```

Every time we need to delay by using `Thread.sleep(25000)` to load the web application (developed using Vaadin framework), instead is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use WebDriverWait instead of the Sleep:

   WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(%your xpath goes here%)));
2. Use more exact xpath, instead of going all the way from the root